# Grouped bar chart data structure issue

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart, with the years on the x-axis, and the median key on the y-axis.
The data structure looks like the snippet under, ie one object per year, containing an array of 2 objects containing themselves what I want to plot.

```
 // Draw bars
 var groups = g.selectAll(".groups")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "groups")

 groups.selectAll("bar")
   .data(function(d) { console.log("d is", d); return d })
   .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.median); })
   .attr("width", 35)
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.median); });
```

Can't get my head around it!

Thanks so much

---

data:

```
const data = [
    {
        "key": "2011",
        "values": [
            {
            "date": "Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+00 (GMT)",
            "median": 7.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "2012",
        "values": [
            {
            "date": "Sun Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+00 (GMT)",
            "median": 7.2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

Edit: [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz2frhet/1/)

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from this function :

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d[dateInput]);
  d.median = +d[medianInput]
});
```

it should be

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.values[0][dateInput]);
  d.median = +d.values[0][medianInput]
});
```

to respect your data